# Rotational Kinetic Energy

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, potential-energy, rotation, moment-of-inertia

So I'm having a bit of an issue in solving equations that involve rotational energy and how to distinguish it from mechanical. For instance, how to set up the energy equation of an atwoods machine, like pictured, in the event of m2 just before it hits the ground and m1 is on a frictionless surface. How do I know if KErot is initial or final is it simply if it is moving? I have this eqn, not sure if it's right: [image]

[image]

Comment: A note to the wording: Instead of saying "*rotational and mechanical kinetic energy*" then say "*rotational and translational kinetic energy*". Both of them are mechanical energies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know if it is the initial or final situation from which values you plug in. The energy conservation equation you have made holds for both situations, only the values change. The only rule is to pick a point in time and then to keep it consistently:

- Are you picking the initial point in time, then you input the initial speeds $v$ (maybe it is zero?) and initial height $h$. The rotational (angular speed) $\omega$ will then also be for this moment.
- Are you picking the final point in time, then you input the final speeds $v$ and final height $h$ (maybe zero). You might have to calculate them first in other ways. And the $\omega$ is as well the angular speed in that final moment.

When you ask if there's only a $K_{rot}$ during rotation, then the answer is the same as for the usual $K_{translation}$: Yes, it is only there during rotation, but you don't have to think about that; the equation solves it for you if you just plug in the right values. Just plug in a zero as $\omega$ if there is no rotation, and then $K_{rot}$ becomes zero as well.

In principle if you were ever in doubt, you could include both a rotational and a translational kinetic energy term as well as a potential energy term for **every object** into the equation. All three for the rotating disc and all three for each of the boxes. But because you can easily see that the disc doesn't translate and that the boxes don't rotate and that the first box and the disc don't change their heights, you skip those terms already in the beginning. But when something moves, there is a kinetic energy term present and maybe also a potential, and are you in doubt which or if, then include all and plug in values.

Comment: Thanks!! So does this mean if this were an inclined atwoods machine with the same masses and pulley, would initial energy include mgh for m2 and m1 (if they were at rest) and then Ef add mgh for m1?

Comment: @Mad If an object changes it's height, then there will be a potential energy term for that one as well, yes. And even if there isn't, you can still include that term when in doubt, because it just becomes zero. See the last paragraph I just added.

Answer (score 0):

$M_{\rm p}$ is a term when evaluating the moment of inertia of the pulley.

Here is the edit [image]which was done by @Mad

Comment: That's not what I'm asking @farcher I know that, I'm asking how to set it up, is my energy eqn correct and how does one know if KErot is initial or final

Comment: If $M_{\rm p}$ becomes larger the moment of inertia of the pulley is increased and so the rotational kinetic energy component is large hence the linear speed of the masses will be less.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that isn't what I'm asking. Is the energy equation that I have up there set up correctly @farcher

Comment: Yes, provided the system started at rest.

Comment: And is there only KErot when a circle is rotating? @farcher

Comment: This does not answer the question. Has there been made a large edit to the question, or where does the $M_p$ come from @Farcher?

Comment: No there wasn't a big change, I had no idea what he was talking about the whole time lol @steeven

Comment: @Steeven The original question was this" . . . . . .  it hits the ground and m1 is on a frictionless surface. Where does mp come into play? I have this: . . . . . . . " As you can see it is significantly different from the current question. You can see what was edited by clicking in the "edited . . . .  . hour ago" link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @Mad You did change the question significantly as is shown when you bring up the previous version.

Comment: Haha, I see ☺️ Life ain't easy. I have removed my downvote.

Comment: @Steeven It was not the downvote ; it was more my spending some time trying to answer a question to find out that it was alleged that the question have never been asked.